# Plotting extracted features

Tags: c++, opencv

I have used the function GoodFeaturesToTrack() to extract the features. My issue is how to plot the features as points on the displayed image?

I want to do that by using either opencv or c++?

Thanks.

Comment: -1 / Vote to close: What's a feature? What type is it? What data are you trying to plot? At least one interface to OpenCV _is_ in C++. Please re-phrase exactly what you're trying to ask here and give some more specifics.

Comment: @JOn, From the function that I use it's obvious that I'm using harris corner detector, I'm extracting the features around the objects in the image and i want to plot them on the image

Comment: For features extracted with `GoodFeaturesToTrack()` function `PlotGoodTrackedFeatures()` should be used.

Comment: @Tadeusz, there is no such function in opencv!!!

Answer (score 0):

The second argument are the points found by the operator.
Just change the corresponding pixels in your image and plot it.

Do you use c++ and opencv? Can you plot images already?
Don't you know how to change the pixles in the image?

Comment: Before I have used this function in optical flow method and I could plot lines between the first frame features and the second one, now I have only one image which i want to plot a point, a cross or whatever on the features place in the image. I wanna know only how to plot that points in the image to show their locations